# Custom error messages on standard salesforce edit view from other object trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, error-messages

When I insert a Case I have a trigger that automatically inserts an opportunity among other things to that Case. When something fails due to an expected error I want to be able to customize the error message and display to the user why it failed. I know this is possible straight from the Case Trigger using caseInstance.addError('customMessage'); but I want to throw the custom message from the Opportunity Trigger handler since this is where it fails in the image below. (This is supposed to fail, I just want to customize a more user friendly message for the user).

Does anyone know if this is possible?
[image]

Comment: Where is the DML message coming from?

Comment: It's coming from inside the Opportunity Trigger. From this method marked in red is the message I want to display when trying to insert the Case:
http://prntscr.com/nsbhbp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the trigger or a central place, I usually add try catch block to handle DML exception and throw error to display appropriate error message. Psuedo code:

```
try {
    // your code
} catch(System.DmlException dmlEx) {
    // handle DML exception to display proper error message
    for (Integer i = 0; i < dmlEx.getNumDml(); i++) {
        Trigger.new[0].addError(dmlEx.getDmlMessage(i));
    }
} catch(System.Exception ex) {
    // handle any other exception
    Trigger.new[0].addError(ex.getMessage());
}
```

There could be a better solution though. But this may be bit better than string manipulation to cut out proper error message.